# java.io.FileNotFoundException while making a post request to the Microsoft qna API

Tags: java, android, post, https, azure-cognitive-services

I have made a post request to the [Microsoft qna makers](https://qnamaker.ai/)  api in android. 
But im getting the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/<My KB ID>/generateAnswer
```

API format to make a post request :

```
    POST /knowledgebases/<Your KB ID>/generateAnswer HTTP/1.1
Host: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v1.0
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <Your Subscription key>
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
{"question": "Question goes here"}
```

I just followed the above specified format and made a post request inside the **getText()** method . And this method is called in the background using **RetrieveFeedTask** class .
Here is the code I used to make a post request:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RetrieveFeedTask task = new RetrieveFeedTask();
            task.execute();
        }
    });
}



// Create GetText Metod
public void GetText() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String text = "";
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    // Send data
    try {

        // Defined URL  where to send data
        URL url = new URL("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/<My KB Id>/generateAnswer");

        // Send POST data request

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "<My Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key>");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        //Create JSONObject here
        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        jsonParam.put("question", "hi");


        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        wr.flush();
        Log.d("karma", "json is " + jsonParam);

        // Get the server response

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;


        // Read Server Response
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Append server response in string
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }


        text = sb.toString();
        Log.d("karma ", "response is " + text);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("karma", "exception at last " + ex);
    } finally {
        try {

            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }


}

class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Log.d("karma", "called");
            GetText();
            Log.d("karma", "after called");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("karma", "Exception occurred " + e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
 }
```

Plese help me out with this...

Comment: Try removing the `host` property of the request

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari , Did that Still getting the same error

Comment: Can you confirm that you are substituting the actual knowledge base ID in place of `<Your KB ID>` (likewise for  the subscription key).  Symptom suggests you may not be.

Comment: yes,@cthrash,im using the actual knowledge base id. Just replaced it with <Your KB ID> while asking the question.